# BeagleBone SPI using mmap

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, spi

I am having trouble configuring my BBB for SPI using a python mmap.

Rather than rolling a device tree overlay myself, I've been using Adafruit_BBIO.SPI (A similar approach has been working for Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO).  This works well, and through SPIdev, I can send data.  But as soon as I use mmap to SPI_TX0, I get a bus error.

I can resolve the bus error by turning on the clock domain to the SPI peripheral:

```
ctrl = struct.unpack('<L', CM_PER[CM_PER_SPI0_CLKCTRL:CM_PER_SPI0_CLKCTRL+4])[0]
ctrl &= ~(0b11 << 16 | 0b11)
ctrl |= 2
CM_PER[CM_PER_SPI0_CLKCTRL:CM_PER_SPI0_CLKCTRL+4] = struct.pack('<L', ctrl)
```

But I don't understand why this is necessary; shouldn't Adafruit_BBIO have already turned the clock domain on?

More importantly, though, is that SPI0[SPI_TX0:SPI_TX0+4] = struct.pack('`<`L', data) does nothing.